# ROS node which broadcasts periodically frames getting from python?

Tags: ros, node, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

Is there a ROS node which I can send with python a frame similar to the addTf() command and the node broadcasts this frame all the time? I want to create, modify and delete frames in one program run/sequenze without broadcast it periodically by myself. So the static_transform_publisher is not the right choice for me.

`<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="app_bcast" args= "0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 p_frame c_frame 100" />`

Thanks in advance!

nico

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/387562/ros-node-which-broadcasts-periodically-frames-getting-from-python?/) by [nicob](https://answers.ros.org/users/85320/nicob/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2021-09-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the docs here: http://wiki.ros.org/tf2_ros

There is the `TransformBroadcaster` class with both a [C++ API](http://docs.ros.org/latest/api/tf2_ros/html/c++/classtf2__ros_1_1TransformBroadcaster.html) and [Python API](http://docs.ros.org/latest/api/tf2_ros/html/python/tf2_ros.html#transformbroadcaster) which will facilitate you publishing transforms.

There's also a `StaticTransformBroadcaster` but if you want things to be changing the main one is likely what you want.

There's also tutorials for how to publish transforms in both C++ and Python here: http://wiki.ros.org/action/show/tf2/Tutorials?

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2021-09-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nicob](https://answers.ros.org/users/85320/nicob/) on 2021-10-05**:
Thanks! The tf2 staticBroadcaster works fine for me! :-)